# How to show custom tooltip message in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm encountering an 'undefined' message after binding 'tooltip' prop in '' element.
I want simply to show tooltip messages on required input fields.

full code: https://jsfiddle.net/8gaysr9u/

in line 16th appending `v-bind:tooltip="tooltip"` at

```
<label>SKU<input type="text" id="sku" v-model="this.product.sku" placeholder="ID"></label><tooltips v-bind:tooltip="tooltip"/>
```

and in line 122th appending `v-bind:tooltip="tooltip">{{tooltip.tooltipText.onSubmit}}`

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext" v-bind:tooltip="tooltip">{{tooltip.tooltipText.onSubmit}}</span>
</div>
```

the console simply thows 'undefined'.
I variated the code in all ways but like against the brick wall the console throws 'undefined'.
What I am doing wrong here??

Comment: You should also share your data options

Comment: you mean from parent component to child component or vise versa?

Comment: Your parent's `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False alarm! :D
Solved by myself. :)

I added to my custom tooltip element:
`:tooltip="this.tooltipText"`

```
<tooltips :tooltip="this.tooltipText" />
```

and in custom component 'tootips':
`v-bind:tooltip="tooltip">{{tooltip.onSubmit}}`

```
<span class="tooltiptext" v-bind:tooltip="tooltip">{{tooltip.onSubmit}}</span>
```

Now my tooltip shows as expected :))